# Can I specify comparator using std::set constructor without specifying all the template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I want to construct a set with lambda comparator. 
Due to known limitations you can not specify lambda as template parameter(you need to `decltype()` it) so I thought about specifying the key of the map in the template argument list and comparator in the constructor argument. 
Something like:

```
std::set<Color> colors({ { "Red", 255, 0 , 0 }, { "Green", 0,255,0 },  { "Black", 0,0,0 } } , [](const Color& a, const Color& b){return a.name()<b.name();});
```

But from what I understand from error message as soon as I specified the template arguments(`<Color>`) I forced others to default(`std::less` for comparator). And the map constructor taking just comparator is not smart enough to get the Key type from comparator arguments, aka this does not work:

```
std::set colors([](const Color& a, const Color& b){return a.name()<b.name();});
```

Is there a way to specify I want a set of `Color`s, but let the comparator be specified by constructor.

Note that I can use constructor to deduce template types since C++17, but it is not pretty since I need to write a lot more than I want.

```
std::set colors(std::initializer_list<Color>{ { "Red", 255, 0 , 0 }, { "Green", 0,255,0 },  { "Black", 0,0,0 } } , [](const Color& a, const Color& b){return a.name()<b.name();}, std::allocator<char/*???*/>{});
```

full code [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Oq8vdo7nLV5WsUgn):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, isn't possible with deduction guides (in C++17) explicit a template type and deduce the others.

If you want deduce the type `Color` from the lambda comparator, the best I can imagine is the creation of a `makeSetFromCmp()` function

```
template <typename Key>
auto makeSetFromCmp (bool(*cmp)(Key const &, Key const &),
                     std::initializer_list<Key> const & il)
 { return std::set(il, cmp); }
```

The trick is that passing first the comparator, the `Key` type can be deduced from the comparator so there is non need of explicit `std::initializer_list<Key>` calling the function.

So you can write

```
auto colors = makeSetFromCmp(+[](Color const & a, Color const & b)
                                   { return a.name() < b.name(); },
                             { { "Red", 255, 0 , 0 },
                               { "Green", 0,255,0 },
                               { "Black", 0,0,0 } });
```

Observe the `+` before the lambda definition: convert the lambda in a good-old function pointer.

A little improved version of `makeSetFromCmp()` (with a third allocator template argument with a default value and with forwarding) could be

```
template <typename Key, typename A = std::allocator<Key>>
auto makeSetFromCmp (bool(*cmp)(Key const &, Key const &),
                     std::initializer_list<Key> && il,
                     A && all = A{})
 { return std::set(std::forward<std::initializer_list<Key>>(il),
                   cmp,
                   std::forward<A>(all)); }
```

Comment: ah, I was afraid of that... BTW I think boost callable traits could enable you to remove the need for + ( you could pass callable and metahack to get the argument type) but in general this answer is very good... so if nobody comes up with a better one soon I will accept it.